# GAN loss doesnt ocsillate but converges relly quickly

Tags: generative-models, gan

I am trying to train a GAN and am getting a strange convergence issue. The losses seem to converge really quickly and dont ocsilate.

The examples of the generator produces are noise.

Both the networks are fullt convolutional and have around 8 million parameters each.

I am using the SGD optimizer with lr=0.0001 for the generator and 0.0004 for the discriminator.

I am wondering if the generator is too good and is able to fool the discriminator early on, so need to make it less powerful, but i find it hard to diagnose GAN training failures.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: how are the outputs?

Comment: It's could be mode collapse for example if the network is outputing the same thing no matter the input

Comment: the network is outputting a blur of colour

Comment: So it's probably mode collapse, your discriminator is not training well

Comment: What type of GAN are you using? Convergence issues are typical in the original GAN variants.